# How to upload image on aws server using node

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multer

I am trying to upload the image on the AWS server using the multer using the following code:

```
//post request
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({  dest: path.resolve('./public/uploads/'), });

/* POST saveblog router. */
router.post('/uploadMedia', upload.any(), function(req, res, next) {

 //console.log("res",res);
 console.log(req.body, 'Body');
 console.log(req.files, 'files');

  var myJSON = JSON.stringify(req.files[0].filename);
  console.log("file name "+myJSON);

  if (typeof myJSON != 'undefined'){
    var obj= new Object();
    obj.status=true;
    obj.message="File Uploaded Successfully";
    obj.type= req.files[0].mimetype;

    var fileExtensionArray=(req.files[0].mimetype).split("/");
    var fileExtension=fileExtensionArray[1];



    res.json(obj);
  }else {
     var obj= new Object();
     obj.status=false;
     obj.message="Error while uploading file try again";

     res.json(obj);
   }

  res.end();
});
```

It is working fine on the local. But when I upload that code to the server and try to hit through the API. The server stops with following logs

```
Change detected on path public/uploads/b690b296bfde62eb8ff527328bc8b463 for app www - restarting
PM2        | Stopping app:www id:0
```

As log says change detected but I am not able to find any image.

As I have searched on StackOverflow and google, I am not able to find tutorial or help to do the same. 
I am getting help regarding the s3 but I don't want to upload on it.

Is it not possible to upload the image to AWS server like that and I have to use S3 or something wrong with my code?

Edit: Now I am able to get the image to the destination folder but still not able to return the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely running PM2 in Watch mode, which is a feature intended to be used in development, to restart your application upon changes to its files. This is *not* intended to be used in production.

To fix this, if you're starting pm2 from the cli use the option

`--no-autorestart`

or the yaml config;

`autorestart: false`